# Setup Moq to increment value when method called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I've got a POCO which im saving, like this:

```
_myRepo.Save(somePoco);
```

`_myRepo` is mocked, e.g:

```
var myRepo = new Mock<IRepo>();
```

When that Save method is called, i want to set `somePoco.Id` to 1.

How do i do it?

I see there is a `Callback` method on the `.Setup`, but it doesn't pass through the POCO, e.g:

```
myRepo.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<SomePoco>())
   .Callback(x => // how do i get the poco?);
```

Comment: Can't you access your `somePoco` through closure? If it's declared as local variable it should be accessible in callback function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parameters get passed to the `Callback` method you just need to specify the types explicitly.

So the following should work:

```
myRepo.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<SomePoco>())) 
       .Callback<SomePoco>(poco => { poco.Id = 1; });
```

See also the samples in the [quick start](https://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart):

```
// access invocation arguments
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Execute(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(true)
    .Callback((string s) => calls.Add(s));
```

Comment: what is calls in the test method?